# merging 2 dynamic 2D arrays into one dynamic 2D array

Tags: arrays

How can I merge two 2D arrays and store it in a new 2D array. 
The 2D arrays I am trying to merge are **child[maxindex][p]**  and **child[m_maxindex][p]**.The arrays are dynamic.

```
    int point = 2;
    for (int p = 0; p < point; p++)
    {
        int Temp3 = Temp_parent1[maxindex][p];
        Temp_parent1[maxindex][p] = child[maxindex][p];
        child[maxindex][p] = Temp3;
        cout << "   " << child[maxindex][p];
    }

    for (int p = point; p <= genes - 1; p++)

    {
        int Temp3 = Temp_parent1[m_maxindex][p];
        Temp_parent1[m_maxindex][p] = child[m_maxindex][p];
        child[m_maxindex][p] = Temp3;
        cout << "   " << child[m_maxindex][p];
    }
```

Comment: By "merge" you mean: (1) append 2 arrays horizontally; (2) append 2 arrays vertically; (3) put 1st array on even places in 3rd array, and put 2nd array on odd places in 3rd array ? In all cases you need arrays to be either equal width or equal height.

Comment: what i am trying to do is a crossover of 2 indivisuals.
23564 and 65389 are two indivisuals. 2 3 3 8 9 is the resultant indivisual( 2 and 3 from 1st indivisual and rest from thesecond ). I am triyng to get child[maxindex][p] and child[m_maxindex][p] in one 2D array

Comment: I am still unable to comprehent the problem :(( Would you be so kind to provide some visual explanation - drawing or something ? Because for me `get child[maxindex][p] and child[m_maxindex][p] in one 2D array` means `put the last row of CHILD as first row into PARENT, then put the second to last row of CHILD as second row into PARENT` .....